# Combining two independent inner joins into one on certain conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below two queries that are shown below, actually both of the queries use an inner join internally. Now I want to combine these two queries into one, but the condition that where the value of `column invo_id = 2` and the column `invo_id` is in table `ioa_invoice_line`

So the relationship among three tables

1. `ioa_invoice_line`
2. `ioa_invoice_line_notes`
3. `IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP`

These are the queries

```
select 
    e.id
    , e.invo_id
    , b.id
    , b.inli_id
from 
    ioa_invoice_line e
inner join 
    ioa_invoice_line_notes b on e.id = b.inli_id;

select 
    e.id
    , b.id
    , b.ATTACHMENT_BLOB_ID
    , b.INV_LINE_NOTE_ID
from 
    ioa_invoice_line_notes e
inner join 
    IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP b on e.id = b.INV_LINE_NOTE_ID;
```

ioa_invoice_line [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbdFa.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I assumed you'd want to do the joins.  Since you're looking for two conditions to be true:
1) That *ioa_invoice_line.invo_id = 2*
2) That *ioa_invoice_line.invo_id exists*

Since you'll be checking to see that invo_id is equal to 2 you can be pretty sure that it exists if it finds a value of 2.

```
SELECT L.id, L.invo_id, LN.id, LNM.id, LNM.attachment_blob_id, LNM.inv_line_note_id
FROM ioa_invoice_line_notes LN
INNER JOIN ioa_invoice_line L ON LN.inli_id = L.id
INNER JOIN ioa_inv_line_note_map LNM ON LN.id = LNM.inv_line_note_id
WHERE L.invo_id = 2;
```

It just looked like you were looking for Inv Line ID, Inv Line Invoice ID, Line Notes ID, Line Notes Map ID and the other IDs in the Notes Map table.

Answer (score 0):

The query integrates the condition on the `invo_id` into the join. As it is an inner join, the existence of `invo_id` in the selected records comes for free:

```
    select line.id                id_line
         , line.invo_id
         , notes.id               id_notes
         , notes.inli_id
         , map.id                 id_map
         , map.attachment_blob_id
         , map.inv_line_note_id
      from ioa_invoice_line       line
INNER JOIN ioa_invoice_line_notes notes on (
                                                 line.id      = notes.inli_id
                                             AND line.invo_id = 2
                                           )
INNER JOIN ioa_inv_line_note_map  map   on map.id = notes.inv_line_note_id
         ;
```